# Usage of Cloud Foundry Spaces in the development chain

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am currently evaluating the possibility of introducing a private Java PAAS cloud. So far I am quite excited about the whole solution, especially combining the foundry with openstack.

What I am wondering though, is how this can be combined with development. I obviously want the developer to run the developed code on the cloud and no longer on his unmanaged workstation.

Is it possible to do the following:

- Developer develops his application code on the local host OS. A virtual machine is used to build and run the application. I have seen this in vagrant and liked this alot. Ideally the local vagrant box is a cloud foundry space.
- If the developer is OK with his code, he should push his application out of the local vm to a developer specific acceptance space run by cloud foundry on the network. Here the application is a more production like environment and automated acceptance / disaster recovery tests can be executed.
- If the developer decides this is OK and merges his changes to the trunk (SVN/GIT) a CI tool should deploy the application to the "global" test, acceptance and production spaces.

I assume the last point is no problem. I just cannot find a way, how the first steps can be achieved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Altoros/cf-vagrant-installer for the first step.

Comment: Hi, I knew about this, but I failed to see a possibility to transition from the local vagrant dev environment to the hosted environments.... Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

are you actually looking for a complete cf deployment on top of openstack?

That can be achieved using BOSH cloud foundry deployment for openstack.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/

you can have different spaces in the cf deployment: test , production etc. and can move application from one space to another after testing is done.